# Rails: How to buffer an ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to save a query, then build on top of it, then execute it.

For example, somehow

```
query = Post.order('likes DESC') # buffer the query
query = query.limit(3) # add on top of it
query.run # run it - this is the wrong syntax fyi
```

Can this be done? What's the right syntax?

PS. I'm not sure if "buffer" is the right word, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any "buffers" when building queries with ActiveRecord in Rails 3 because it uses [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel). Your `query = Post.order('likes DESC')` gives you instance of ActiveRecord::Relation. This object contains information about query, but not an actual data. To get data you can invoke `.first` or `.all` methods for example. It's way how rails framework (>= 3.0) implements so called "lazy initialization". It means that ActiveRecord::Relation is a kind of proxy. Real query to the database goes only when you're trying to get some fields of your model (or when you force load data with .all, `.first`, `.last` etc). Until this action you can build your chain of filtering conditions and be sure that you do not "disturb" database.
Your code may be like this:

```
query = Post.order('likes DESC') # ActiveRecord::Relation object with info about your query
query = query.limit(3) # adds more filtering options
@posts = query.all # here ActiveRecord takes data from the database
```

[#239 ActiveRecord::Relation Walkthrough](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough) will give you more understanding about ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: The behavior I see on the console is consistent with what you say except the last part, `query.all`. For me `.all` returns everything in spite of what conditions might have been set previously.

Comment: In addition to `.first`, `.last` etc causing records to load, you can explicitly call `.load` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AREL and Rails 3 this happens automatically. AREL will built up a query as you chain options and execute the query when you call `.all` or start accessing data through any other means.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly how ActiveRecord works. When it hits an iterator or some other non-AR method, it calls the database using the built-up query. It works a little different in the console, because I believe the `.inspect` method is called to display the output after you press return.

It's fine to do what you've proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveRecord::Relation#load` method to force database hit:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load